# How to construct an aggregation pipeline to filter documents based on field values in other documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If the document collection contains:

```
{ _id: "1", name : "doc1", myDocRefId : "" }
{ _id: "2", name : "doc2", myDocRefId : "" }
{ _id: "3", name : "doc3", myDocRefId : "1" }
```

I want to construct an aggregation returning only the documents **not** being referenced by any other documents via my myDocRefId field. For this collection I would like to return:

```
{ _id: "2", name : "doc2", myDocRefId : "" }
{ _id: "3", name : "doc3", myDocRefId : "1" }
```

Doc 1 is removed in the aggregation because doc 3 has a reference to it.

How can this be done in an aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "myDocRefId",
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      tmp: {
        $size: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "tmp"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jlS10iPEwEW) | [$graphLookup](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FjnpXwQ7-IJ)